# Excel Pivot Table with external Data Source parameter is not saved with workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have a pivot table in an excel 2007 workbook that links to an external data source. The query is along the lines of "exec procedure @param=?" (using an ODBC connection to sql server 2005). I am using a cell reference to provide the value for this parameter. This works fine, but when you save the book and re-open it the reference is lost and if you try to refresh the pivot table (without fixing this) then the application crashes.

Any neat work arounds would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The work around I've used is to effectively put the value I was using (from the cell reference) into a table in the database (a parameters table). It's not brilliant but its worked for me in this case. The procedure now takes an optional parameter and if the parameter is not supplied then it uses the value in the database table.